# How can I access md-dialog onComplete from within dialog controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

$mdDialog.show accepts an `onComplete` function which is triggered once the show action is complete.  See https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#show.

How can I get that same onComplete functionality but from within the dialogs controller (not the parent controller calling the dialog)?

Comment: What are you needing to accomplish?

Comment: Setting focus, but I want it handled by the dialog controller (not the parent controller).

Comment: SImple workaround...broadcast an event

Comment: that would work, I actually found a way using a deferred promise passed through as a local variable to the dialog, and then the onComplete function resolves the promise.  This still feels messy but I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the parent  controller:

```
var onCompleteDeferred = $q.defer();
$mdDialog.show({
    templateUrl: '/app/dialog.html',
    controller: 'dialogController',
    onComplete: onCompleteDeferred.resolve,
    locals: {
        loadingPromise: function () {
            return onCompleteDeferred.promise;
        },
        success: function() {}
    }
})
```

Within the dialog's controller:

```
myApp.controllers.controller("dialogController", [
    "success",
    "loadingPromise",
    function (
        success,
        loadingPromise
    ){
        loadingPromise().then(function() {
            //everything in here is guaranteed to be ran AFTER the dialog has been opened
        });
    }
)
```